# WAMP loaded (green icon), but keep loading localhost or localhost/phpmyadmin without any success

Tags: ms-security-essentials, wamp

I do not know if it is a virus/trojan horse, but I am not able to use my WAMP.

I mean, I turn off all other program like skype (I know about the port isssues, but this is not this case I guess), email client, so nothing excet default windows programs are installed.

Then I start WAMP and it goes through all stages red->orange->green so I guess everything is loaded properly.

However, whenever I try to open localhost or phpmyadmin it keeps on loading...and loading... but nothing shows up... it says page is loading etc...

Btw. I have a red flag in my windows and if I try to start Microsoft Security essentials I get this message:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to make sure your browser is not using any proxy settings, that will most definately cause your browser from being unable to access your server on the localhost. It could be that or obviously something else, but worth a check if you use proxies. If you do use proxy and it is causing the problem, in Firefox you have a no proxy field, enter your localhost ip in there.